# {h-schema} causing illegal character

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring-data-jpa and for one business use case, I have to write a native SQL query.

For the native query, I am trying to define the schema using property {h-schema}. However, the SQL is failing with the following exception

ERROR:

```
syntax error at or near "`"
Position: 169
```

Native SQL Query

```
String sql = "select a, b from {h-schema}test"
```

Hibernate Generates the query

```
select a, b from `hello`.test
```

Schema configuration:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        default_schema: hello
```

Database: PostgreSQL
Operating System: Mac